# Calculating the number of shapes after cutting v-shaped from a rectangular board.

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Firstly I want to say sorry because I have collected it from a running programming contest but `I can't stop myself from knowing the system`.
Please help me about finding the number of shapes after cutting v-shaped from a rectangular board.

```
More info in the image .
```

if the v-shaped cut is 1 - total shapes will be 2.

if the v-shaped cut is 2 - total shapes will be 7.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

No of pieces after $n$-cuts can be given by: $$a_n=a_{n-1}+4n-3$$  where $a_1=2$.

Comment: You should explain how you got this.  I think you are assuming you can cross every existing vee in four places, but that is not obvious as the number of cuts increases.

Comment: currently a contest question btw